# Draw with finger in html on ipad?

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, canvas, touch

I´m trying to write with finger in canvas element. It works on desktop browsers but not in the ipad.
I try with touchstart, touchend, touchmove event too, but it doesn´t work on ipad.

```
var pizarra_canvas
var pizarra_context

function init(){            
    pizarra_canvas = document.getElementById("pizarra");
    pizarra_context = pizarra_canvas.getContext("2d");
    pizarra_context.strokeStyle = "#000";
    pizarra_canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',empezarPintar,false);
    pizarra_canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',terminarPintar,false);
    }   

function empezarPintar(e){
pizarra_context.beginPath();
pizarra_context.moveTo(e.clientX-pizarra_canvas.offsetLeft,e.clientY-pizarra_canvas.offsetTop);
pizarra_canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',pintar,false)
}

function terminarPintar(e){
pizarra_canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove',pintar,false);
}

function pintar(e) {
pizarra_context.lineTo(e.clientX-pizarra_canvas.offsetLeft,e.clientY-pizarra_canvas.offsetTop);
pizarra_context.stroke();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cancel the default event (which is scrolling). Additionally, it is better that you trigger mouseup/touchend on the document because if you leave the dragging area and release the button then the canvas doesn't know it should stop drawing.

```
var pizarra_canvas
var pizarra_context

function init(){            
    pizarra_canvas = document.getElementById("pizarra");
    pizarra_context = pizarra_canvas.getContext("2d");
    pizarra_context.strokeStyle = "#000";
    pizarra_canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',empezarPintar,false);
    pizarra_canvas.addEventListener('touchstart',empezarPintar,false);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup',terminarPintar,false);
    document.addEventListener('touchend',terminarPintar,false);
    }   

function empezarPintar(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  pizarra_context.beginPath();
  pizarra_context.moveTo(e.pageX-pizarra_canvas.offsetLeft,e.pageY-pizarra_canvas.offsetTop);
  pizarra_canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',pintar,false)
  pizarra_canvas.addEventListener('touchmove',pintar,false)
}

function terminarPintar(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  pizarra_canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove',pintar,false);
  pizarra_canvas.addEventListener('touchmove',pintar,false)
}

function pintar(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  pizarra_context.lineTo(e.clientX-pizarra_canvas.offsetLeft,e.clientY-pizarra_canvas.offsetTop);
  pizarra_context.stroke();
}
init();
```

Also, your css should have something like this on touch devices:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}​
```

Comment: At the first, thank you. Now when you touch the canvas element the page doesn,t scroll but it still not painting.

Comment: use `e.pageX` and `e.pageY` instead of `e.clientX` and `e.clientY` and let me know if that works. I've updated the code in the answer.

Comment: It works perfectly!! Muchas Gracias!! I knew the problem was something related to name of the touchEvent clientX property, but I haven´t found anything about it. Can you tell me where have you found this info?

Comment: I recall having the same problem as you and I found this page where I could inspect touch events http://gregmurray.org/ipad/touch-events.html but it seems to be down for me at this moment. Tal vez tengas más suerte.